# jsonapi-resources—overriding fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, jsonapi-resources

There's a field in my resource that I want to set to `1` if it's `nil` in the model. I have the following code, but the resource is still producing `minimum_approvers: nil`

Any ideas on what's going on?

```
module V1
  class EntityResource < BaseResource
    model_hint model: Entity

    attribute :logo
    attribute :minimum_approvers

    def minimum_approvers
      @model.minimum_approvers.nil? ? 1 : @model.minimum_approvers
    end
```

Comment: Can you `byebug` `minimum_approvers` method and check value is nil or not? Is it empty string?

Comment: I tried byebug in the `minimum_approvers` method—it never even ran, the resource just uses the field with the same name in the model.

Comment: why don't you consider `before_save` callback in your model and set the value there? and according to the docs, it should inherit from `JSONAPI::Resource` as `class EntityResource < JSONAPI::Resource`

Comment: http://jsonapi-resources.com/v0.9/guide/resources.html#Attributes

Answer (score 0):

If the method you want to call has the same name as the model's attribute, you can't override it. The best you can do is make a method in the model that does the logic, then call the method in your resource.

Comment: this is one of the reasons why I prefer `fast_jsonapi` - doing things the Rails way results in more productivity for the developers..

Comment: btw. even defining the method in the model does not seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Just to flesh out the answer by @Mirror318 and to respond to the comment by @Tilo, the following worked for me with V0.10.7 of jsonapi-resources:

```
module V1
  class Entity < ApplicationRecord
    def minimum_approvers_with_default
      minimum_approvers || 1
    end
  end
end

module V1
  class EntityResource < BaseResource
    attribute :minimum_approvers,
              delegate: :minimum_approvers_with_default
  end
end
```